# mount: overlapping loop device

Tags: filesystems, mount

I getting these problems when I try to mount this filesystem DOS/MBR

```
#file bag.vhd 
bag.vhd: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x83, active, start-CHS (0x0,1,1), end-CHS (0x9,254,63), startsector 63, 160587 sectors


#sudo mount -t auto -o ro,loop,offset=82252288 bag.vhd /mnt/floppy/
mount: /mnt/floppy/: overlapping loop device exists for /home/ffha/Documents/descon/bag.vhd.
```

I have been created /mnt/floppy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got `82252288` from. You should also specify the `sizelimit` for the partition you are trying to mount.

The partition table is best inspected with `fdisk -l` rather than `file`, which also allows you to confirm the sector size.

Assuming it is 512 bytes, this will mount the first partition on that disk:

```bash
sudo mount -o ro,loop,offset=32256,sizelimit=82220544 bag.vhd /mnt/floppy
```

63 × 512 = 32256
160587 × 512 = 82220544